# Recover Hardware Raid Disk

Tags: linux, raid, partition-recovery

I have an issue with a raid disk and I was not able to find a solution. I have an Asus Rampage IV Extreme with an Intel controller for raid. I was using 2TB disk in raid 1 with multiple partitions, 2 for Windows and 3 for Linux. The system was working fine but my power source died, now I;m trying to access my HD data from a different computer, the problem is that when I plug the disk in the new computer I can only see the two windows partitions but not the linux partitions, Both disk have the same issue. I tried a different computer with no luck.

This is the output of dmesg

```
[ 1843.533102] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST2000DM 001-9YN164            PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1843.534757] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1843.535817] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[ 1843.536680] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1843.536686] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[ 1843.537423] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 1843.537428] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1843.541439] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 1843.541446] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1843.566463]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 1843.570044] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 1843.570048] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1843.570051] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

And this is the output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x480e9f3d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848  1614587903   807190528    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I am running Debian Wheezy 64 bits, which was the same installation I had.

Comment: What sort of RAID configuration exactly?  You will need to connect both drives in the same configuration to have any chance of data recovery.  Have you thought about replacing the PSU to acomplish this?

Comment: Yes, I will get a PSU next week but I was hopping to have my data sooner.
I have two hard drives, which are mirrored in a Raid-1. I was using the intel chip provided on the motherboard.

Comment: I'm surprised that all the Linux partitions have vanished from fdisk

Comment: Well based on a thread on a discussion forum I read, it appears you should be able to just read a single disk in the array, but clearly in read-only access.  Have you looked at both disks?

Comment: Yes, I looked at both disks. In both I have the same windows partitions but not linux partitions. Thanks for the prompt response.